# How to pop a modal view with Three20?

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20

I have a modal view controller name: ComposeMessageViewController. And main view controller name: MainViewController.
In MainViewController i map an URL to ComposeMessageViewController like this:

```
[map from:@"up://home/messages/compose_message/" toModalViewController:[ComposeMessageViewController class]];
```

In MainViewController i call this modal view:

```
TTURLAction *urlAction  =   [[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"up://home/messages/compose_message/"] applyAnimated:YES];
[[TTNavigator navigator]    openURLAction:urlAction];
```

But i don't know how to remove(dismiss) ComposeMessageViewController when i done with it. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a button with the delegate set to `self` and the selector set to `dismissModalViewController`.